# foreach loop with condition in c#

Tags: c#, foreach, conditional-statements

I have this foreach loop in c#, since i am new to c#, i was wondering if this can be written shorter (have the condition part of the loop

```
foreach (PagerPageFilterInformation filter in PageFilterInformation)
{
    if (filter.Ancestor == myParent)
    {
        DoSomething()...//Using filter
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried doing :

```
PagerPageFilterInformation filter = PageFilterInformation.FirstOrDefault(filter => filter.Ancestor == myParent);
if(filter != null)
{
DoSomething()...}
```

But it didnt work. could it be because the class:

```
PagerPageFilterInformation
```

Inherits from the class :

```
PageFilterInformation
```

?

Comment: Are you using `filter` in your `DoSomething`, or are you actually just "if it exists, do this"?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, yes i am using it.

Comment: You are programming in which version of .Net ? All the answers given below will work, only if you are using .net 3.0 or above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends if you need to use the first `filter` when you `DoSomething` (which it seems like you do). But yes, you could shorten this code using LINQ.

If you need the `filter`:

```
var filter = PageFilterInformation.FirstOrDefault(filter => filter.Ancestor == myParent);
if(filter != null)
{
    DoSomething()...
}
```

If not, you could use the [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) method.

```
if (PageFilterInformation.Any(filter => filter.Ancestor == myParent)
{
    DoSomething()...
}
```

Comment: The first option is exactly what i tried doing, but it doesnt work, could it be because the class `PagerPageFilterInformation ` inherits form the class `PageFilterInformation`?

Comment: Is it because the enumerable isn't of this type? Try putting `.Cast<PagerPageFilterInformation>()` before the `.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: Brilliant! Yeah this is because a foreach loop automatically casts each item to the type you specify, LINQ doesn't though.

Answer (score 5):

If `DoSomething()` method does not use found filter:

```
if (PageFilterInformation.Any(filter => filter.Ancestor == myParent))
{
   DoSomethng();
}
```

**EDIT:** Update since new requirements was provided in comments

If you need pass found filter into the `DoSomething()` method:

```
var filter = PageFilterInformation.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Ancestor == myParent);
if (filter != null)
{
   DoSomething(filter);
}
```

Comment: `DoSomethng` here can't use the `filter`. You also have a bracket mismatch in the if statement.

Comment: @Connell Watkins : this requirement was posted 4min ago since my answer was posted 5 mins ago

Comment: that is exactly what i tried doing, but it doesnt work, could it be because the class PagerPageFilterInformation inherits form the class PageFilterInformation?

Comment: @Ovi: Does this work? - `foreach (PagerPageFilterInformation filter in PageFilterInformation) `? BTW, coudl you specify which interfaces implement `PageFilterInformation`  class

Comment: yes, `foreach (PagerPageFilterInformation filter in PageFilterInformation)` works fine

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (PagerPageFilterInformation filter in PageFilterInformation.Where(f => f.Acestor==myParent))
        {
                DoSomething()...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `filter` variable, I would use this construct:

```
var filter = PageFilterInformation.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Ancestor == myParent);
if (filter != null)
{
    DoSomething(filter);
}
```

Code becomes easier to read since I don't have to read through the loop and figure out that it stops at the first found element.

Comment: that is exactly what i tried doing, but it doesnt work, could it be because the class PagerPageFilterInformation inherits form the class PageFilterInformation?

Comment: PageFilterInformation is not a class, that's an object. Isn't it? It has to be if you want to enumerate over it...

Answer (score 0):

If PageFilterInformation is an IEnumerable you can use the System.Linq's extension Where method;

Having shorter code doesn't mean more efficient, you should understand what these statements actually produce as IL.

Comment: Readability is just as important as efficiency, if not more important. Ideally I'd go for both, and with languages like `C#`, usually the most readable code is the most efficient. I'd rather save a few minutes of my time when I go back to read my code a few months later than a few milliseconds of processing time.